# .show() and .toggle() will not reveal final game screen in trivia game

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide, show

I have gone over and over the code. I've tried to show the final game screen (result-screen) with JQuery and then again by defining global variables. I have called it as part of another function and within its own function. No combination I come up with is displaying my final result-screen.

```
var welcome = $("#welcome-screen")
var gameOver = $("#result-screen")
var game = $("#game-screen")

var playerInteract = {
    correctAnswers: 0,
    incorrectAnswers: 0,
    unanswered: 8,
    seconds: 10,
    //done: false,

    welcome: function() {
        gameOver.toggle();
        game.hide();
    },

    initiate: function() {
        welcome.hide();
        game.show();
        playerInteract.timer();
    },

    timer: function() {
        var windowTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            //playerInteract.gameOver() 
            game.hide()
               playerInteract.answerCheck()
               playerInteract.gameOverLoad()
            },  10000);
        var intervalVariable = setInterval(playerInteract.decrement, 1000);
        var seconds = playerInteract.seconds;

    },  

    decrement: function () {
        if (playerInteract.seconds >= 2) {
                playerInteract.seconds--;
                console.log("seconds: " + playerInteract.seconds);
                $("#countdown").text(playerInteract.seconds);
            }
    },
   gameOverLoad: function() {
       gameOver.show();
       console.log("gameover");
   }

};


window.onload = playerInteract.welcome;

$("#start-button").on("click", function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault()
    playerInteract.initiate()
});

$("#countdown").text(playerInteract.seconds);
```

<----HTML---->

```
<div id="welcome-screen" class="container">

    <img id="header" src="assets/images/header-image.png" alt="Stephen King Killer Trivia">
    <h1>Take a stab at it!</h1>
    <button id=start-button><h2>STAB!</h2></button>

</div>

<div id="game-screen" class="container">
    <img id="header" src="assets/images/header-image.png" alt="Stephen King Killer Trivia">

    <h2>Take a stab at it!</h2>
    <h3>Time Remaining: <div id="countdown"></div></h3>

    <img id="penny" src="assets/images/penny.png" alt="Pennywise the clown.">

    <h4>What's the name of the killer clown in Stephen King's novel, <em>IT</em>?</h4>

        <div class="answer-boxes">
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="wrongA"> Torchy
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="wrongB"> Quarterdumb
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="correct1"> Pennywise
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="wrongC"> Boinko
        </div>

    <img id="georgie" src="assets/images/georgie.png" alt="Georgie from 'It'">

    <h4>Which King protagonist went crazy and killed<br> most of her classmates and teachers during prom?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="wrongD"> Sandy
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="wrongE"> Dolores
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="wrongF"> Sherrie
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="correct2"> Carrie
        </div>

    <h4>Stephen King regularly contributed to <em>Dave's Rag</em> in high school.</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" class="radio-button" id="correct3"> True
        <input type="radio" name="q3" class="radio-bitton" id="wrongG"> False
        </div>

    <h4>What year and model car was featured <br>in the movie <em>Christine</em> based on a Stephen King book?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="wrongH"> 1962 Ford Mustang
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="wrongI"> 1957 Chevy Chevelle
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="wrongJ"> 1951 Jaquar XK 120
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="corrcet4"> 1958 Plymouth Fury
        </div>

    <h4>Mike Hanlon made seven phone calls in Stephen King's novel, <em>IT</em>.</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" class="radio-button" id="wrongK"> True
        <input type="radio" name="q5" class="radio-button" id="correct5"> False
    </div>

    <h4>What's the name of Stephen King's western/fantasy saga?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="correct6"> <em>The Dark Tower</em>
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="wrongL"> <em>The Darkest Hour</em>
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="wrongM"> <em>The Dark Knight</em>
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="wrongN"> <em>The Dark Travels</em>
    </div>

    <h4>Which of the below is a Stephen King pseudonym?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="wrongO"> Dick Hallorann
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="correct7"> Richard Bachman
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="wrongP"> Sam Paul
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="wrongQ"> Benjamin Sanders
    </div>

    <h4>One of Stephen King's jobs prior to publication was as a high school teacher.</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" class="radio-button" id="correct8"> True
        <input type="radio" name="q8" class="radio-button" id="wrongR"> Flase
    </div>

<div id="result-screen" class="container">

    <img id="header" src="assets/images/header-image.png" alt="Stephen King Killer Trivia">

    <h1>All Done!</h1>
    <h4>Correct Answers: <div id="correct-answers"></div></h4>
    <h4>Incorrect Answers: <div id="incorrect-answers"></div></h4>
    <h4>Unanswered: <div id="unanswered"></div></h4>

</div>
```

The only code I have eliminated from my JS is the answerCheck function.

After the setTimeout concludes, I want the game screen to hide and the result screen to show. Hide, show, toggle all work in the code up until the timeout finishes.

The game screen hides, leaving the background the only thing visible. The console.log to print gameover to the log runs. No errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT. Ok, I think the div "game-screen" is missing the closing div tag in the html. I updated it in the snippet below.

I also commented out playerInteract.answerCheck() as that function is not in the code like you mentioned, and it fires an error.

```js
var welcome = $("#welcome-screen")
var gameOver = $("#result-screen")
var game = $("#game-screen")

var playerInteract = {
    correctAnswers: 0,
    incorrectAnswers: 0,
    unanswered: 8,
    seconds: 10,
    //done: false,

    welcome: function() {
        gameOver.toggle();
        game.hide();
    },

    initiate: function() {
        welcome.hide();
        game.show();
        playerInteract.timer();
    },

    timer: function() {
        var windowTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            //playerInteract.gameOver() 
            game.hide()
               //playerInteract.answerCheck();
               playerInteract.gameOverLoad();
            },  10000);
        var intervalVariable = setInterval(playerInteract.decrement, 1000);
        var seconds = playerInteract.seconds;

    },  

    decrement: function () {
        if (playerInteract.seconds >= 2) {
                playerInteract.seconds--;
                console.log("seconds: " + playerInteract.seconds);
                $("#countdown").text(playerInteract.seconds);
            }
    },
   gameOverLoad: function() {
       gameOver.show();
       console.log("gameover");
   }

};


window.onload = playerInteract.welcome;

$("#start-button").on("click", function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault()
    playerInteract.initiate()
});

$("#countdown").text(playerInteract.seconds);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="welcome-screen" class="container">

    <img id="header" src="assets/images/header-image.png" alt="Stephen King Killer Trivia">
    <h1>Take a stab at it!</h1>
    <button id=start-button><h2>STAB!</h2></button>

</div>

<div id="game-screen" class="container">
    <img id="header" src="assets/images/header-image.png" alt="Stephen King Killer Trivia">

    <h2>Take a stab at it!</h2>
    <h3>Time Remaining: <div id="countdown"></div></h3>

    <img id="penny" src="assets/images/penny.png" alt="Pennywise the clown.">

    <h4>What's the name of the killer clown in Stephen King's novel, <em>IT</em>?</h4>

        <div class="answer-boxes">
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="wrongA"> Torchy
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="wrongB"> Quarterdumb
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="correct1"> Pennywise
            <input type="radio" name="q1" class="radio-button" id="wrongC"> Boinko
        </div>

    <img id="georgie" src="assets/images/georgie.png" alt="Georgie from 'It'">

    <h4>Which King protagonist went crazy and killed<br> most of her classmates and teachers during prom?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="wrongD"> Sandy
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="wrongE"> Dolores
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="wrongF"> Sherrie
        <input type="radio" name="q2" class="radio-button" id="correct2"> Carrie
        </div>

    <h4>Stephen King regularly contributed to <em>Dave's Rag</em> in high school.</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" class="radio-button" id="correct3"> True
        <input type="radio" name="q3" class="radio-bitton" id="wrongG"> False
        </div>

    <h4>What year and model car was featured <br>in the movie <em>Christine</em> based on a Stephen King book?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="wrongH"> 1962 Ford Mustang
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="wrongI"> 1957 Chevy Chevelle
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="wrongJ"> 1951 Jaquar XK 120
        <input type="radio" name="q4" class="radio-button" id="corrcet4"> 1958 Plymouth Fury
        </div>

    <h4>Mike Hanlon made seven phone calls in Stephen King's novel, <em>IT</em>.</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" class="radio-button" id="wrongK"> True
        <input type="radio" name="q5" class="radio-button" id="correct5"> False
    </div>

    <h4>Wha's the name of Stephen King's western/fantasy saga?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="correct6"> <em>The Dark Tower</em>
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="wrongL"> <em>The Darkest Hour</em>
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="wrongM"> <em>The Dark Knight</em>
        <input type="radio" name="q6"class="radio-button" id="wrongN"> <em>The Dark Travels</em>
    </div>

    <h4>Which of the below is a Stephen King pseudonym?</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="wrongO"> Dick Hallorann
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="correct7"> Richard Bachman
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="wrongP"> Sam Paul
        <input type="radio" name="q7" class="radio-button" id="wrongQ"> Benjamin Sanders
    </div>

    <h4>One of Stephen King's jobs prior to publication was as a high school teacher.</h4>

    <div class="answer-boxes">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" class="radio-button" id="correct8"> True
        <input type="radio" name="q8" class="radio-button" id="wrongR"> Flase
    </div>

</div><!-- #game-screen -->


<div id="result-screen" class="container">

    <img id="header" src="assets/images/header-image.png" alt="Stephen King Killer Trivia">

    <h1>All Done!</h1>
    <h4>Correct Answers: <div id="correct-answers"></div></h4>
    <h4>Incorrect Answers: <div id="incorrect-answers"></div></h4>
    <h4>Unanswered: <div id="unanswered"></div></h4>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In cutting and pasting, I failed to include the onload call for the welcome function. The post has been edited. I also included the full body of my HTML.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. I don't have enough words to thank you. Three hours of my life. **Learning code is fun.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no error and it is working now after you had made those changes.